# jQuery selectors, selecting parent of div based on inner html

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a section of html that looks like this:

```
<div id="faq-content">
   <div class="faq-topic" >
      <div id="faq-content-title">Top Questions</div>
      <div class="faq-item"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="faq-topic">
      <div id="faq-content-title">Returns</div>
      <div class="faq-item"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Given the text "Returns" or "Top Questions" how could I select its respective parent "faq-topic" div? I was able to select the "faq-content-title" div using $('.faq-content-title:contains("Returns")'), but I couldn't figure out how to select the parent.

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything wrong with using `$('.faq-content-title:contains("Returns")').parent()`?

Comment: If your structure isn't quite as reliable as you posted, then you can also use `closest` to get the first parent using the faq-topic class. `$('.faq-content-title:contains('Returns').closest('.faq-topic')`

Comment: @JeffB That was it. I was thinking in terms of css selectors only. Thanks!

Comment: @bazmegakapa: Fixed.  I just copy/pasted TomM's snippet. Whoops.

Comment: @Jeff Looks much nicer now ;).

Answer (score 0):

you can try this ...

```
$('.faq-content-title:contains("Returns")').parents('.faq-topic');
```

hope this helps ..

Comment: `.closest()` would be better than `.parents()`, as `.parents()` will return *all* elements that match, while `.closest()` will return the *first* element that matches.